# Lua "or" statement issue

Tags: lua

I'm very new to Lua, and I'm doing a very simple  text based adventure thing, but it wont work. My code is as follows:

```
while input ~= ("leave cave" or "leave") do
print("What do you want to do?")
input = io.read()

if input == "inspect" then 
        print("You are in a cave") 
    elseif input == "leave cave" or "leave" then
        print("You leave the cave")
    elseif input == "inv" then
        for i,v in pairs(inv) do
        print(i, v)
    end
  else
    print("You didn't write a valid command...")
  end
end

-- leave cave

input = ""
print("What do you want to do?")
input = io.read()
while input ~= "follow path" do 
if input == "inspect" then 
        print("You are at the base of a hill. There is a path.") 
    elseif input ==  "follow path" then
        print("You follow the path. There is a gate.") 
     elseif input == "inv" then
        for i,v in pairs(inv) do
        print(v)
        end
    else 
        print("That's not a valid command...")
    end 
end
```

What I'm trying to do is have it so whenever the user types leave, or leave cave, it proceeds to the next segment (the path one), however, when I type "leave" and then type "inspect" again it says "I am in a cave" rather than what it should be saying which is saying that you left, and you see a path. And when I type leave cave, and then inspect, it spams "You are at the base of a hill. THERE IS A PATH" over and over, indefinitely.

And when I type "inv" it doesn't print my inventory, and instead prints "You left the cave," but doesn't actually leave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a or b` can't make a value that means "either a or b" -- that would be too complicated.

In fact, if you ask it to choose between two strings, it will just pick the first:

```
print("leave cave" or "leave") --> leave cave
```

`or` is only meant to be used on booleans -- you have to combine it on multiple *full conditions*:

`while (input ~= "leave cave") and (input ~= "leave") do`

In this case, a `repeat ....... until <condition>` loop might serve you better:

```
repeat
    print("What do you want to do?")
    input = io.read()

    -- <do stuff>
until input == "leave" or input == "leave cave"
```

Comment: So, this works, but will this work on anything that's not a boolean? As in this code

    `if input == "open gate" or "inspect" then 
      print("The gate is locked. You spot a key sticking out of the     grass.") 
     elseif input == "inv" or "inventory" or "showinv" then
      for i,v in pairs(inv) do 
      print(i, v)
     end
     else 
      print("That's not a valid command...")
    end`


would i be better do to input == "open gate" and input == "inspect" then...

Comment: You always need to be explicit and repeat your `==` or whatever else you mean. If you need to do this a lot, maybe write a `matchesAny` function that would allow you to write `if matchesAny(input, "open gate", "inspect")`

Answer (score 0):

While `or` cannot accomplish such a complex operation, it is possible to recreate the effect yourself with some hacky metatable code.

Please note *I do not reccomend using this code in any serious professional or commercial programs, or really at all for that matter*, this code is inefficient and unecessary, however it is a fun piece of code to do exactly what you're looking for. It's just a fun way to experiment with the power of Lua.

```
local iseither
iseither = setmetatable({},{
   __sub = function(arg1,arg2)
      if arg2 == iseither then
         arg2.Value = arg1
         return arg2
      else
         if type(arg2) ~= "table" then
            error("Second operator is -iseither- was not a table",2)
         else
            for i,v in ipairs(arg2) do
               if arg1.Value == v then
                  arg1.Value = nil
                  return true
               end
            end
            arg1.Value = nil
            return false
         end
      end
   end
})

print(1 -iseither- {1,2,3,4,5})
```